# What Azure CLI api corresponds to the terraform azure provider's resource azurerm_app_service_certificate?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to troubleshoot a certain problem I have with creating an Azure App Service Plan with terraform. It is a regression, that was not there a couple of months ago.

As part of the troubleshooting I would like to create the same infrastructure using Azure CLI. This would let me know if the problem is in terraform provider or in Azure itself.

Specifically my question is how do I create the `azurerm_app_service_certificate` resource with Azure CLI?

Comment: I'm not sure what azurerm_app_service_certificate means, but See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#azure-cli

Comment: I have seen it. But the question remains.